# Error "cannot coerce class '"formula"' into a data.frame" when using lme function

Tags: r

I'm trying to execute a lme function as follows

```
mydata <- read.table(
    "H:/edu/Multivariat/HCMpart2.TXT", header=TRUE, sep="\t",
    na.strings="*", dec=",", strip.white=TRUE
)
mydata = data.frame(mydata)

summary(lme(mydata$x~1+mydata$grp+mydata$var, random~1|mydata$id))
```

where x contains my values, grp and var represent which groups and variables that caused the x value, and id is the id of the patient.

And where HCMpart2.txt contains a header with "id grp var x" with tabs in-between and the corresponding values for all these. I've tried to use the "as.numeric" function to convert the factors into numerical factors, but it did not complete my problem.

When I'm trying to execute the lme function I get the following

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
cannot coerce class '"formula"' into a data.frame
```

Can anyone help? I was under the impression I did everything correctly...
Regards
Cenderze

Comment: You are missing an `=` sign. It should be `random = ~1|mydata$id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three things:

Like shadow said, you're missing an equals sign in the random argument.

`lme` has a `data` argument that stops you having to write ugly code with lots `$` signs.

The intercept is implicitly included.

```
summary(model <- lme(x ~ grp + var, mydata, random = ~ 1 | id))
```